# Changing position of card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this 5 cards in a row from top to bottom.

```
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            News 1
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                <p>Hello.</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-header">
            News 2
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                <p>Hello.</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse; ">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to put these 2 cards to the right sides of other 3 cards. what should I do?

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem; flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse; ">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how can i do it as I spesified?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Bootstrap as I see the 'twitter-bootstrap' tag in your question. You can utilise the default classes provided by Bootstrap itself to achieve the solution you are aiming for.

Try the following code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          News 1
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>Hello.</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-header">
          News 2
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>Hello.</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-header">
          News 3
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>Hello.</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <hr style="height: 2px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray ">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also added the classes so that on smaller screens all the cards are stacked one-below-the-other but on a medium screen you will see the cards side-by-side as expected.